Allow only authorized connections to nRF52840
This is my current example code. It configures bluetooth, and then waits for bytes sent from PC client (service guid is 6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E, and characteristic guid is 6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E). Shortly speaking it works.
#include <bluefruit.h>

const int LED_PIN = D7;

BLEDis bledis; 
BLEUart bleuart; 

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Bluefruit.begin();
  Bluefruit.setTxPower(4); 
  Bluefruit.Periph.setDisconnectCallback(onDisconnect);
  Bluefruit.Periph.setConnectCallback(onConnect);

  bledis.setManufacturer("Seeed Studio");
  bledis.setModel("XIAO nRF52840");
  bledis.begin();
  bleuart.begin();
  startAdv();
}

void loop() {
  if (bleuart.available()) {
    delay(2);
    uint8_t buffer[3];
    int bytesRead = bleuart.read(buffer, 3);
    if (bytesRead == 3 && buffer[0] == 0 && buffer[1] == 0 && buffer[2] == 0) {
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    }
    if (bytesRead == 3 && buffer[0] == 1 && buffer[1] == 0 && buffer[2] == 1){
      digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
    }
  }
}

void startAdv(void) {  
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addFlags(BLE_GAP_ADV_FLAGS_LE_ONLY_GENERAL_DISC_MODE);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addTxPower();
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addService(bleuart);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.addName();
  Bluefruit.Advertising.restartOnDisconnect(true);
  Bluefruit.Advertising.setInterval(32, 244);    
  Bluefruit.Advertising.setFastTimeout(0);      
  Bluefruit.Advertising.start(0);                
}

void onDisconnect(uint16_t conn_handle, uint8_t reason) {
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
}

void onConnect(uint16_t conn_handle){
  //empty for now
}


But there is an issue. nRF52840 is visible to every device that has bluetooth, I can pair them together which will lock out the "authorized" clients. I absolutely can't figure out how to configure it to accept only authorized connections.
I basically want to achieve this:

nRF52840 is not visible to things like bluetooth settings on a smartphone
it can only be detected and connected to from desktop application

I have been thinking about setting up a password that both nRF and application knows, but so far no success. There is really not a lot of documentation about that either which doesn't help at all.
